# $.getJson not working in IE

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

Ok, for some reason my getJson is not working. I am pulling some stock information and it works in all major browsers except IE.

I have created a JSfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/qZhSk/

If anyone can help me understand what I am doing wrong it will be SUPER helpful.

thanks!

**EDIT**

I found the solution myself. The issue was in my URL query. If anyone else has this issue here is the answer:

```
var url = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20WHERE%20symbol%3D'NPO'&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys";

        $.getJSON(url + "&format=json&callback=?", function(data) {
        var items = [];

        $.each(data.query.results.quote, function(key, val) {

            items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');
        });

        $('<ul/>', {
            'class': 'my-new-list',
            html: items.join('')
        }).appendTo('body');
)};
```

Answer (score 8):

Technically, I think you're violating the Same Origin Policy on this one.  By definition, you can't do a JSON get from a domain other than your own....and getting data from Yahoo is certainly a different server than jsFiddle's.  There is a [similar issue reported here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8364993/gwt-web-app-trying-to-get-json-from-php)  The CORS exceptions they list are IE up to version 10, which would explain the issue perfectly.

The problem could be solved by using a "?" in your callback handler.  [See this stack article](http://e-mats.org/2010/01/jquery-getjson-and-the-same-origin-policy/) for more info.

Comment: That's exactly what I noticed.  Basically you'll need to add a `&callback=?` to the end of your url string and you're golden

Comment: The weird thing is that it worked in Firefox. *edit* ah - CORS

Answer (score 1):

Since its a old post this answer may be helpful to other seekers.

There may be two reasons why getJson not working in IE.

1.Either Jsonp requests which resolved by adding

```
 &callback=? or &callback=?
```

2.Set ajax catch.

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

If still you have problem, it may be because of the cross-platform API usage.

Answer (score 0):

I'll go for the well known [cross domain policy issue with jquery and IE](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/cross-domain-ajax-and-ie).

This article explain well the solution:

http://cypressnorth.com/programming/cross-domain-ajax-request-with-json-response-for-iefirefoxchrome-safari-jquery/