# HTTP Get JSON issue in IE, works in Chrome FF

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, plugins

I am trying to use a simple weather plugin and make it smart so it figures out what location a user belongs to by calling a geolocation service based on IP. Works in Chrome, FF. Not IE though. What is wrong or why is IE having issues with the following??
 I seem to be having this cross-domain call issue here..
Full Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XfhQK/1/

```
 jQuery.getJSON('http://freegeoip.net/json/', function(data) {
     jQuery.simpleWeather({
        zipcode: data["zipcode"],
        woeid: '',
        location: '',
        unit: 'f',
        success: function(weather) {
          html = '<h2>'+weather.temp+'&deg;'+weather.units.temp+'</h2>';
          html += '<ul><li>'+weather.city+', '+weather.region+'</li>';
          html += '<li class="currently">'+weather.currently+'</li>';
          html += '<li>'+weather.tempAlt+'&deg;C</li></ul>';

          jQuery("#weather").html(html);
        },
        error: function(error) {
          jQuery("#weather").html('<p>'+error+'</p>');
        }
     });

});
```

Comment: More details about the error, please?

Comment: data["zipcode"] should grab the zipcode property from the JSON object, but it looks like  data["zipcode"] was empty or something so the weather plugin shows no weather result. Works in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/XfhQK/1/

Comment: Put `console.log(data)` before the simpleWeather call, and include the output in your question (press F12 to open the IE dev tools, where the console is).

Comment: Also, I believe you're having a cross-domain request issue. Maybe the remote domain allows CORS and the other browsers are sending the proper headings, but not IE?

Comment: This is using a CORS request (Access-Control-Allow-Origin).  IE 8 and 9 need special treatment to make it work.  Should work in IE 10.

Comment: IE8- How do I make it work in IE8 then? It's not possbile?

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8448934/getjson-not-working-in-ie

Comment: @SarikaThapaliya: You need to use a thing called `XDomainRequest`, which jQuery doesn't seem to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The URL you are accessing uses `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` (aka CORS).  This is *not* supported in IE 8 or 9.  IE 10 supports it, however.

Anyway, the easiest way to fix it is to include [this plugin](https://raw.github.com/jaubourg/ajaxHooks/master/src/xdr.js) that adds `XDomainRequest` support to jQuery.

You also need to change to using `$.ajax`.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://freegeoip.net/json/',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'GET',
    crossDomain: true
    success: function(data){
        // ...
    }

});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/XfhQK/4/

<sub>Plugin Homepage: https://github.com/jaubourg/ajaxHooks

Found at: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8283</sub>

Answer (score 3):

For anyone with similar issue, passing the URL in this format:

```
http://freegeoip.net/json/?callback=?
```

instead of just:

```
http://freegeoip.net/json
```

worked for me.

More explained here:
 http://e-mats.org/2010/01/jquery-getjson-and-the-same-origin-policy/
and here [$.getJson not working in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8448934/getjson-not-working-in-ie)

Thanks everyone who helped me get to the solution.